# using matplotlib to plot a bar char with time data in x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns, one is a series of time date in string format, and the other is some value. I'd like to plot this dataframe into a bar chart

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':['090000','093000','100000','103000'],'b':[2,3,4,5]})
df['a']=pandas.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%H%M%S')

fig = plt.figure()

ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(df['a'],df['b'])
```

but I found this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

how can I solve this problem?? thanks

Comment: That's strange. I'm able to see the bar plot with the same code. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: python 3.5 x64, I know... one of my friend can see the bar chart with the same code via version 3.4...

Comment: using pandas-0.17.1, even using pandas-0.18.0 still get the same typeerror...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on python 2.7 when upgrading matplotlib from version 1.4.3 to 1.5.1

Going back the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (matplotlib 1.5.1). In my case I could resolve it by setting date variable as an index, and then plotting bar chart against data frame index. I.e. in the code above, before plotting, one would need to add

```
df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
```

and then plot with

```
ax1.bar(df.index, df['b'])
```